# Como limpar a Output Window do Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estou escrevendo uma aplicação que faz uso do classe debug para escrever na tela Output do VS.

Só que eu gostaria de limpar o conteúdo desta tela através do meu código, pois depois de um tempo ele fica muito poluído. Isso é possível e recomendável (pois acho estranho não ter um método clear para essa classe)?

Comment: Você consegue by Marshal e restrito à versão do VS que você está usando, mas essa prática não faz muito sentido, se o objetivo é log, existem diversas outras alternativas mais enxutas. Ainda mais que ao fazer o deploy da sua aplicação ela deve ser compilada em modo Release, não debug.

Answer (score 0):

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627384/how-to-programatically-clean-output-in-visual-studio-2013

```
// Import EnvDTE and EnvDTE80 into your project
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;

protected void ClearOutput()
{
    DTE2 ide = (DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
    ide.ToolWindows.OutputWindow.OutputWindowPanes.Item("Debug").Clear();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ide);
}
```